# Boolean Theorems - Simplify Function

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am currently taking a Discrete Mathematics course, along with Intro to Hardware course. I am having issues wrapping my head around Boolean Theorems, simplifying functions given to smaller circuit design. One problem that I am working on at the moment is:

> **F**`(a,b,c)` = (A + C)(AB + AB`) + AC + C

I want to apologize for the formatting, but I did not see a shortcut in the toolbar above to format it correctly. I read through the theorems in the book, but I ended up finding my self more confused then I started with. I am looking for assistance in simplifying the function above, and also any help on tackling functions in the future.

I did construct a truth table to help determine how to simplify the function. From looking at the truth table, I did see that (A+C) & the function above have the same output. This conclusion seems as if (A+C) would be the simplified version of the original function, or at least be in the simplified version.

I know it is plain suicide taking both courses together, but somehow I have to overcome this hurdle. I appreciate any help provided.

Thank you,

***~ KeiU***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some equalities that should get you to simplify your expression to $A+C$:

**Adjacency**

$AB+AB'=A$

$(A+B)(A+B')=A$

**Absorption**

$A+AB=A$

$A(A+B)=A$

Comment: Hello,  So, my truth table was right, that I should be working to simplify it towards **(A +C)**?  I appreciate your answer, and working it out now.

Comment: @KeiU. So were you able to get to $A + C$?

Comment: Hello @Bram28, I was able to get it work and really appreciate your reply!